# Why aren't there many (voltage controlled) variable capacitors above ~1000pF?

Tags: capacitor

I was looking into finding a variable capacitor to implement in a closed-loop self-tuning RF circuit and [I noticed](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/capacitors/trimmers-variable-capacitors/65?FV=-8%7C65&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25) there aren't many options above 1000pF and I got curious. Do they not exist because they are difficult to manufacture above a certain capacitance? Or is it because there aren't any use-cases for variable capacitors above 1000pF? Or is there another component that fills this criteria?

Comment: .I can think of many uses for big varicap diodes.

Comment: You asked about voltage controlled capacitors but you linked to trimmer caps.

Comment: @DKNguyen The category I linked is "Trimmers, Variable Capacitors", look closer - it contains both trimmer caps and voltage controlled caps. Unless I'm looking in the wrong place? Let me know if you find a better keyword/category.

Answer (score 8):

Voltage controlled capacitors ([varicaps or varactors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varicap)) are diodes.

A reverse biased diode acts like a (small) capacitor.  The capacitance varies depending on the applied reverse bias voltage.

Varicaps are designed to have a larger capacitance than normal diodes.  Still, you are limited in the amount of capacitance you can squeeze into the junction of a single diode.

Driving a varicap usually requires a little bit of surrounding circuitry to keep the DC from getting into the tuned circuit and to keep the RF from getting out over the DC supply:

[image]

<sub>Image from Wikipedia</sub>

All of the ones you linked to are four port devices that include most of the supporting circuitry.

In many RF circuits, it is common to use an inductor to couple in the DC control voltage rather than a resistor.

---

Speculating, I'd say its just too difficult to make diode junctions with really high capacitance.  I'd also bet that the maximum capacitance has an effect on how fast you can vary the capacitance - I expect a bigger varicap will change capacitance in response to a voltage change slower than a smaller varicap.

Comment: I expect they could do it if there was a market. Varicaps up to 500pF were pretty common when AM radio was popular (1970s) but they are like Instamatic film and Betamax tapes now. That's not because they are harder to make.

Answer (score 4):

If you're happy with a capacitance variation of perhaps only 2:1 or 3:1, with a large temperature coefficient, and a capacitance in the order of 1uF or so, then you could use small package modern ceramic capacitors as varicaps.

Dielectrics like Y5U have a ferocious voltage coefficient. Unfortunately, a designation like that does not specify the dielectric completely, and manufacturers of small package (0603) and large value (1uF and more) ceramic capacitors are free to use any actual dielectric. This means that if you want a reproducible voltage to capacitance curve, you need to pick one package size, capacitance, nominal voltage, and manufacturer, and then hope they don't change ceramic during the life of the product. The full data on voltage coefficient is rarely easy to find, it is embarrassing for suppliers to admit that their 16v 1uF capacitor is actually only that at 1v, and drops to 300nF at 16v. However users with unstable LDOs (due to insufficient capacitance) noticed, so if you ask hard enough they will provide data.

The real answer to why there aren't large conventional diode varicaps is that there's insufficient market demand. If enough people wanted them, then suppliers would be making chips with 100s or 1000s of varicaps in parallel on a single die. Look at power MOSFETs for instance, they are 1000s of cells in parallel made to a price. In fact, look at the capacitance curve for high current MOSFETs in the 1 to 10v region, capacitance frequently >1nF.

Comment: You learn something new every day! Thanks for this, I didn't know it. It opens a lot of ways to play with it.